# Worm fanfic where Panacea encounters a minion of her father's, who convinces her to withhold her healing until Marquis is released

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, worm

I'm looking for a *Worm* fanfic where Panacea encounters a minion of her father's, who convinces her to withhold her healing until Marquis is released. Took a quick gander through the [fanfic recs on TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/FanficRecs/Worm), but no dice. Timeline is close to that in the regular series. While acting as Panacea at a Brockton Bay hospital, she's approached by a former minion of her father, I think just released from jail. He basically just discusses the old days, and makes her realize her father, while not necessarily a good man, isn't nearly as evil as most of the villains out there, and that he got railroaded into the Birdcage. After the minion dies (maybe from brain cancer, since Panacea explicitly "doesn't do brains" through much of the series), she decides she's going to try to get some justice for her father. Part of it is refusing to do the healing she's been doing for free in hospitals and for local heroes. A compromise is first reached where nanobots are smuggled into the Birdcage to allow the two to have a conversation, but I think near the end of the time when I stopped reading (probably due to no more chapters), she was close to getting him released.

I probably read this within the last five years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the search terms I used, because I apparently found it this morning, but initially discounted it, leaving it in a tab to check out later. ["Hostage Situation"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11438292/1/Hostage-Situation) by Ack. Fred Jones is the name of the henchman, and he basically dies because he took a shot long ago from a superhero named Radian, which had long-term effects. And yes, Amy threatens to go on strike:

> I shook my head. “No joke. I want Marquis released into my custody.”
>
> “Or what?” Her glare was ferocious. “What will you do?”
>
> “Nothing.”
>
> She stared at me. “ … what?”
>
> “I said, nothing.” I stared back at her. “I won't do anything. I won't heal anyone, ever again. I won't fix the Wards' injuries. I won't visit the hospitals. I won't do anything. Not until my father gets out of prison.”
>
> Putting my hands on her desk, I leaned forward. “Director Piggot … I want my dad back.”

Comment: Funnily enough, a new chapter came out for this one recently...